# error while deploying flask app on heroku : Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'

Tags: flask, heroku, web-deployment

i am trying to deploy my very simple flask app on heroku but when i try to access my heroku app its giving me this error: `An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.` i checked logs from the terminal and it says: **Failed to find attribute 'app' in 'app'**.

**Code**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "VatsalayKhobragade.me"
```

**Project Structure**

[image]
*

**Procifle**

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

**Requirements.txt**

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Please Help with this. what i am doing wrong here ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably could be solved with the procfile:

`web: gunicorn app.app:app`

---

Although for clarity you may wish to rename the top-level `app` folder to something different, then have:

`web: gunicorn something.app:app`

Or create a `something/__init__.py` file with the contents:

`from .app import app`

Then simply have a procfile with:

`web: gunicorn something:app`

Comment: changed my Procfile as you've said and IT WORKED ! although i will consider your suggestions. Accepted the answer (:

Answer (score 1):

You have a folder called `app` and a top-level file called `app.py` which acts as the entry point for your application.

It fix this error, you will need to change the entry point file name to something else, such as `blog.py` (or any other name you may want).

Update your `Procfile`:

```py
web: gunicorn blog:app
```

Alternatively, you can rename the `app` folder to avoid this conflict

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. In my case I was using `APP` attribute instead `app`.
When replacing `APP` with `app`, the problem fixed.

```
APP = create_app() # correct one -> use app in all lower case 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP.run() # correct one -> use app in all lower case
```